# UPS with form based authentication

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I am working with SharePoint 2013, I have a web application with form based authentication and the user profile sync service connected to the same web application.

My question is how UPS handle the profile of form based authentication users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a Synchronization connection for FBA authentication provider in User profile service application via Central Administration->Manage Service Applications->User profile service application->Configure Synchronization connections.

Reference: [SharePoint 2013 User Profile Sync for Claims Users](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2013/05/23/sharepoint-2013-user-profile-sync-for-claims-users/)

Comment: Is it synched by default?

Comment: Any update?!?!?